# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TemporaryFile'

Tags: python, import

I am new to python.And i am learning the standard library.

Whenever i run the code below , it always raise the `AttributeError...` 
And it seems like there is something wrong with the import command.

Also , i try to run it on the interactive interpreator,and it works just fine.

## The sample code

```
import tempfile
import os

#temp = tempfile.TemporaryFile()
temp = tempfile.mktemp()

print "tempfile","=>",temp

file = open(temp,"w+b")
file.write("*" * 1000)
file.seek(0)
print len(file.read()),"byte"
file.close()

try:
   os.remove(temp)
except OSError:
   pass
```

## The error output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tempfile.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/home/zhkzyth/codeRep/pytest/tempfile.py", line 5, in <module>
    tempfile = tempfile.mktemp()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'mktemp'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 66, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 12, in <module>
    import subprocess, tempfile, os.path, urllib, re, pwd, grp, os
  File "/home/zhkzyth/codeRep/pytest/tempfile.py", line 5, in <module>
    tempfile = tempfile.mktemp()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'mktemp'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tempfile.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/home/zhkzyth/codeRep/pytest/tempfile.py", line 5, in <module>
    tempfile = tempfile.mktemp()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'mktemp'
```

## My enviroment

- ubuntu12.04
- python2.7

Comment: Are you really having AttributeError ? Please report the full exception traceback

Comment: Add `print tempfile.__file__` just below the imports to debug what is being imported there.

Comment: @joaquin,I have updated it.

Comment: Is it running now ? Or do you have a new error ?

Comment: @joaquin,it works now.I rename it to temp.py.=)

Comment: Ok, do not understand. your code (copy/pasted) gaves me a TypeError for the reasons indicated in my answer... I am on windows, maybe there is some difference...

Comment: @MartijnPieters , `print tempfile.__file__`  is a very handy command.Thanks!!

Comment: @joaquin , You are right.The code in my question will raise type error. I did not meet the error after i fix the first problem,the file name conflict with the module name.Should i update the code??

Comment: @joaquin , i have updated the code. It should work in both python2.7 and greater. By the way , the code sample is from the book <Python Standard Library>,written By Fredrik Lundh.You may find it on the tempfile chapter.At last,really thanks for your help.And please forgive my poor english.=)

Comment: @joaquin: the reason your code worked differently than the OP's is that his code never got to the `open` call, because it raised an `AttributeError` on line 4.  And that's because he named the file `tempfile.py`, so it was importing itself rather than the tempfile module from the standard library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you name your own file `tempfile.py`?  If so, rename it, delete all your *.pyc files, and try again.

PS: providing the actual text of the error with the traceback would tell us these things.

Comment: Yes,you are right.I temporarily name it `tempfile.py`,and run it in shell by the command `python tempfile.py`.

Answer (score -2):

Trying to access an attribute that does not belong to a class or function in a module raises an AttributeError exception, the attribute might have been deprecated in a later version of the Python interpreter being used. I suggest you check the version of the Python you're running and make sure your dir(module) includes the attribute you're trying to use

Comment: "might have been deprecated"?  You can look up the docs and be sure.

Comment: The OP stated they are using Python 2.7; `tempfile.TemporaryFile` is a valid class in Python 2.7.